# QRubberBand: crash with BAD ACCESS error

Tags: qt

I'm getting a crash with some `QRubberBand` code that is straight out of the Qt help. The crash occurs at the `setGeometry` call. The `QRubberBand` instance has been created since I am able to access the geometry with qDebug, so I'm confused.

The context for this: the code is in a custom Widget which is created like this:

```
   ImageLabel2* image = new ImageLabel2(this);
   image->setPixmap(pix);
   setCentralWidget(image);
```

I know the instance persists because commenting out the `setGeometry` call to avoid the crash, the debug statements continue to be output.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

**Debug output:**

> mousePress QPoint(294,343)
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.

---

**From crash log:**

> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000

---

**Code:**

```
void ImageLabel2::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "mousePress" << event->pos();

    origin = event->pos();

    if (!rubberBand){
        rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this); 
    }
    qDebug() <<  rubberBand->geometry();
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, QSize())); // CRASH
    rubberBand->show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD:** according to new info, the problem is with initialization.

By having the check

```cpp
if (!rubberBand){
    rubberBand = // initialize it
}
```

You expect the `rubberBand` pointer to be initially equal to zero (NULL), and you check for it. But unless you initialized this pointer, it will be equal neither 0 nor some correct address. Like any other uninitialized variable, it will contain *garbage*, i.e. some random value that happenned to be in the memory by the moment. Using such pointer will guarantee crashes.

So, say no to uninitialized variables! If you want it to be initially NULL, **make it** NULL.

So, in your custom widget constructor initialize it like

```cpp
ImageLabel2::ImageLabel2() : rubberBand(NULL) {
    // your constructor code
}
```

or

```cpp
ImageLabel2::ImageLabel2() {
    rubberBand = NULL;
    // your constructor code
}
```

(there is no difference). Or write `0` instead of `NULL` if you prefer, but `NULL` is more common.

After that, no modification should be needed for `mousePressEvent` method.

---

*Old answer (wrong):*

From the documentation for [QSize default constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsize.html#QSize):

> QSize::QSize ()
>
> Constructs a size with an invalid width and height
>   (i.e., isValid() returns false).

So, you create an *invalid* QSize and pass it to a QRect. The crash after that might be some kind of bug in the code of either QRect or QRubberBand, or kind of *undefined behaviour*. If you want a size of 0 by 0, then you should use a `QSize(0,0)`, I think. Such size would be *valid*:

> bool QSize::isValid () const
>
> Returns true if both the width and height is equal to or greater than 0; otherwise returns false.

Comment: Thanks - I'd checked that and tried using `QRubberBand::setGeometry(int x, int y, int width, int height)` with the same crash. I've narrowed it down to the conditional `if (!rubberBand)`never getting entered, so the object is never created. Odd.

Comment: Then check if `rubberBand` field is initialized to `NULL` in constructor. Otherwise this pointer may contain *garbage* thus being incorrect while not being equal to 0.

Comment: That code is from Qt help; `rubberBand` is declared in my custom Widget header but not initialized until the first mouseDown event (lazy loading), so that conditional should trigger but doesn't. If I explicitly initialize `rubberBand` in my class constructor then it works as expected.

Comment: I mean, if you want lazy loading, you constructor **do must** have some `rubberBand = NULL` assignment, otherwise the pointer will have undefined value that is pointing to nowhere. It will not become `NULL` by itself as you expect it to do. I'll update my post with the example.

Comment: Hey thanks. Of course I blame Qt help for leading me astray ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You error come probably from the fact that you are passing a `QSize()` as parameter.

As the documentation state, the default constructor of QSize create an invalid object